# Problem using useRoutes when redirecting with params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to set up my project for the first time using useRoutes and lazy loading with children. But I am having a problem that it won't load the children when redirected to that site? The Home page works perfectly fine.

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-rgb-ippuob?file=/src/Page/Home/index.js
Home path="/"

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello Welcome to my beauty page</h1>
      <Link to="/1">click me</Link>
    </>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

Children:

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
const Id = () => {
  const { id: loadingId } = useParams();
  return <h1>Right now you are on the side of: {loadingId}</h1>;
};
export default Id;
```

App.js:

```
import "./styles.css";
import Route from "./Routes";
import { Suspense } from "react";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
          <Route />
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Routes:

```
import { useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
export default function Router() {
  return useRoutes([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Home />,
      children: [{ path: "/:id", element: <Id /> }]
    }
  ]);
}
const Home = React.lazy(() => import("./Page/Home"));
const Id = React.lazy(() => import("./Page/Id"));
```

And in Index I have

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `<Outlet />` in Layout/Parent component (Home for you)

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello Welcome to my beauty page</h1>
      <Link to="/1">click me</Link>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
export default Home;
```